# Replicate REST API with SOAP

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-ws

I have a simple REST api which sends data in JSON such as this:

```
http://myapp/color (POST w/ data in JSON) - Creates a new color in DB
http://myapp/color/id (GET) - Fetches details for a color from DB
http://myapp/color (GET) - Fetches details for all colors in DB
```

I would like to create a SOAP API for these three functions as well. So I'm going with Spring-WS.

I've created the SOAP API for the creation. With the following XSD

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:hr="http://www.myveryimportantcompany.com/tr/schemas"
           targetNamespace="http://www.myveryimportantcompany.com/tr/schemas"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="ColorRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Color" type="hr:ColorType"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="ColorType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ColorResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I've also written functional test for the above which works fine.

**Questions** - I've never created a SOAP WS in the past so please ignore if questions are stupid.

- How would the XSD look like for the remaining two functions?
- Do I need a separate XSD for each function?
- Can I test the SOAP service with a GUI as well? I gave SOAP GUI a show but it needs a WSDL. How can I create that?

PS: I'm using Spring-WS plugin from grails.

Comment: You asked for it, you have it. :-). Have a look at the latest version of [springws plugin](https://github.com/dmahapatro/grails-springws) and corresponding [sample app](https://github.com/dmahapatro/grails-springws-sample). Review and let me know if you have any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of a subjective question I bet. I will try to answer as much elaborated as I can to make it useful. Bear with me. :)

**First Thing First:-**

- [SpringWS](http://grails.org/plugin/springws) plugin uses contract-first webservice. The schema which you have created here  should be a contract for the underlying webservice.
- Each of the webservice should have its own contract which means its own schema.
- SpringWS follows a convention of creating an `Endpoint` with the name same as the name of the contract `schema`.
- You can use inheritance in the endpoints which will help you create a single xsd schema for all the contracts. In that case you have to inherit the parent endpoint in the corresponding child endpoints.

**Example:-**
For everyone's convenience lets use a `User` service instead of `Color`.

```
//Domain:-
class User{
    String name
    String email
    Integer age
}
```

I would prepare a base schema for this entity, some what similar to what you did earlier for `Color`:

```
<!-- User.xsd -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:hr="http://www.myveryimportantcompany.com/tr/schemas"
           targetNamespace="http://www.myveryimportantcompany.com/tr/schemas"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:complexType name="UserType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="age" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="User" type="hr:UserType"/>

</xs:schema>
```

Now come to each contract for each Service:-

```
<!-- GetUserService.xsd -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:hr="http://www.myveryimportantcompany.com/tr/schemas"
           targetNamespace="http://www.myveryimportantcompany.com/tr/schemas"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="GetUserRequest" type="hr:GetUserRequestType"/>
<xs:complexType name="GetUserRequestType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="GetUserResponse" type="hr:GetUserResponseType"/>    
<xs:complexType name="GetUserRequestType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="hr:User"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Similarly you can have `UpdateUserService.xsd` doing the update [POST, PUT] piece.

Alternatively, you can accumulate all the xsds to a single contract named `UserServices.xsd`

**Caveat**
In case you have only one xsd for all service then you have to create a parent endpoint named (exactly same) as `UserServicesEndpoint.groovy` (see springws docs how to create endpoints), then your services endpoint would belike

`class GetUserServiceEndpoint extends UserServicesEndpoint{....}`
`class UpdateUserServiceEndpoint extends UserServicesEndpoint{....}`

In case you have all xsds separate, you do not need the inheritance.

**Answers to Questions:**

1. *How would the XSD look like for the remaining two functions?*
   By now you know how should it look. The names should be something like `UpdateColorService.xsd`, `GetColorService.xsd`, `GetAllColorsService.xsd`
2. *Do I need a separate XSD for each function?*
   Follow above. You can have separate or you can have them in one parent xsd. In that case, there has to be a parent endpoint as well.
3. *Can I test the SOAP service with a GUI as well? I gave SOAP GUI a show but it needs a WSDL. How can I create that?*
   Yes you can. The best tool I found is [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) (free version is sufficient for me). You can also use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), if you are comfortable with it. Contract-first services **always** need a WSDL to run. As part of SpringWS plugin, you have a splendid DSL support which creates a WSDL for you after you run the application. Follow the docs again. I can explain that in a different question, because this answer has become an epic by now.

**Words of Advice:**

- Finally, why do you need a SOAP Service when the whole world is RESTing in peace? :)
- springws plugin is almost obsolete and has not been supported for years. I have customized the plugin to my need and have not submitted it to Grails PLugins yet. Did not feel like? But I think I have to now, since @Anthony is using it. :)
- The plugin has jars inside project's `lib` directory which may clash with your dependencies.
- Plugin uses old version of `spring-ws-core` which is definitely going to crash with `spring-core:3.1.2` which comes with `Grails 2.2.x`.
- You might get compilation errors with newer version of JDK (7 or above).

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. I will go with three different XSD with Three Different endpoint approach for now. Some people still aren't RESTing in peace, so for them, SOAP is a necessity :(. I was not aware of lack of support for spring-ws and other related problems you've mentioned. If your customized plugin has solved any of these, I'd love to get an update from github maybe. I'm on 2.1.2 so I haven't encountered the clash yet. Finally, is there something else you recommend for SOAP webservice support in grails?

Comment: I have not played around with it but you can use [Wslite](http://grails.org/plugin/wslite). I had worked in springws before moving to REST. One benefit with springws plugin I forgot to mention was it's ability to intercept payload request/rensponse and validate them against the contract. It is documented as [Adding Endpoint Interceptor](http://grails.org/plugin/springws)